# What is the best condition between negative and positive numbers to avoid repeating comparisons?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to make a bunch of comparisons between numbers, both negative and positive and based on that trim the number `toFixed` decimal points, but I would like to avoid lengthy conditions. Here's a code sample:

```
if (
    (numberValue > 100 && numberValue < 999) ||
    (numberValue > -999 && numberValue < -100)
  )
    scalarNotation = numberValue.toFixed(0);
  else if (
    (numberValue > 10 && numberValue < 99) ||
    (numberValue < -10 && numberValue > -99)
  )
    scalarNotation = numberValue.toFixed(1);
  else if (
    (numberValue > 1 && numberValue < 9) ||
    (numberValue < -1 && numberValue > -9)
  )
    scalarNotation = numberValue.toFixed(2);
  else if (
    (numberValue > 0 && numberValue < 1) ||
    (numberValue < 0 && numberValue > -1)
  )
    scalarNotation = numberValue.toFixed(3);
  else if (numberValue > 1000 || numberValue < -1000)
    numberValue.toFixed(4);
```

What is the best way to refactor and perhaps to convert the number to absolute value, add a flag to indicate if the number is positive or negative, and then you can multiply by the modifier at the end?

Comment: When you tried to "convert the number to absolute value" what problem did you have with that logic?

Comment: It almost looks like an attempt to do `numberValue.toPrecision(3)`

Comment: One wonders what you intended to have happen with a number like 1 or 99, or 99.5 that does not fall within any of your ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to simplify the problem.

You can store the checks inside an array of objects, where you specify the limit and the number of decimals. Then, test each one on the absolute value, and return the first match:

```js
function test(num){
  const abs = Math.abs(num)
  const tests = [
    {limits: [100, 999], toFixed: 0},
    {limits: [10, 99], toFixed: 1},
    {limits: [1, 9], toFixed: 2},
    {limits: [0, 1], toFixed: 3},
  ]
  
  let res;
  tests.forEach(({ limits, toFixed }) => {
    if(!res && abs > limits[0] && abs < limits[1]) {
      res = num.toFixed(toFixed)
    }
  })
  return res || num.toFixed(4)
}

console.log(test(0.5))
console.log(test(5))
console.log(test(15))
console.log(test(150))
console.log(test(-150))
console.log(test(1500))
```

Comment: You should add `test(1)` as a test case.

Answer (score 0):

Make simpler and easier

```js
const decimalFn = ( n ) => {
  let dec;
  n = Math.abs(n)
  if(n <= 999) dec = 0
  if(n <= 99) dec = 1
  if(n <= 9) dec = 2
  if(n <= 1) dec = 3
  return n.toFixed(dec)
}

console.log( decimalFn(-99) )
console.log( decimalFn(-9) )
console.log( decimalFn(-1) )
console.log( decimalFn(0.5) )
console.log( decimalFn(1) )
console.log( decimalFn(9) )
console.log( decimalFn(99) )
console.log( decimalFn(999) )
```

Comment: And what about negative numbers?

Comment: Added run updated code